# How to convert 'date' format to UTC format

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xquery, xslt-2.0

In the below example we are trying to convert 'date' from one format to other like as want to convert into UTC format e.g. 2021-07-26T18:37:15.490Z

Can anyone help.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<date>
<finish_dstamp>20190716140831</finish_dstamp>
</date>
```

**EXISTING OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<date>
<finish_dstamp>20190716140831</finish_dstamp>
</date>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Reference URL:** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dB/1

Comment: What kind of value does `20190716140831` represent?

Comment: @Martin Honnen - It's represent "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format

Comment: But in your question you give the input format example as `20190716140831` but the result format example as `2021-07-26T18:37:15.490Z`, are these values not related? If the input has all the values just not in the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` the `xs:dateTime` constructor needs you can just use the `replace` function with the right pattern to extract the subcomponents and the right replacement string inserting the `-` or `T` or `:` separator between the subcomponents.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - Yes, I shared the result as an example. and want to convert input should be look like as it. please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also parse out the date and time components with regex. An example of regex and capture groups to construct the dateTime value (which you could also parse as dateTime to ensure is valid)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="finish_dstamp/text()">
        <xsl:sequence select="replace(., '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An example using `xsl:analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:template match="finish_dstamp/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\d{{4}})(\d{{2}})(\d{{2}})(\d{{2}})(\d{{2}})(\d{{2}})">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:sequence select="xs:dateTime(
                string-join((
                  string-join((regex-group(1),regex-group(2),regex-group(3)), '-'), 
                  string-join((regex-group(4),regex-group(5),regex-group(6)), ':')), 
                'T')) "></xsl:sequence>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

You could parse out the components of the date and time, and then use the [`fn:dateTime()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-dateTime) function with `xs:date()` and `xs:time()` params, and put that in a specialized template matching on the `finish_dstamp/text()` node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="finish_dstamp/text()">
        <xsl:sequence select="dateTime(
            xs:date(
              concat(
                substring(., 1, 4), 
                '-',
                substring(., 5, 2),
                '-',
                substring(., 7, 2)
              )
            ),
            xs:time(
              concat(
                substring(., 9, 2),
                ':',
                substring(., 11, 2),
                ':',
                substring(., 13, 2)
              )
            )
          )"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could parse out the components of dateTime and use the `xs:dateTime()` constructor:

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
version="2.0">

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="finish_dstamp/text()">
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:dateTime(
          concat(
            substring(., 1, 4), 
            '-',
            substring(., 5, 2),
            '-',
            substring(., 7, 2),
            'T',            
            substring(., 9, 2),
            ':',
            substring(., 11, 2),
            ':',
            substring(., 13, 2)
          )
        )"/>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please see the issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556765/how-to-transform-xml-text-into-table-format